# Vuejs display other input fields based on selected value from dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vueJS application I have a component with a select list

```
<!-- Schedule type -->
<div class="container mx-auto flex bg-white px-6 py-1 space-x-2">
    <dashboard-input-label class="col-sm-2 mb-2 w-full" identifier="schedule_type">
        Schedule type
    </dashboard-input-label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 mb-6 w-full">
        <validator-v2
            :identifier="identifier"
            :rules="rules.schedule_type"
        >    
            <cs-dashboard-select
                :options="[
                    { value: '1', label: 'On duty'},
                    { value: '2', label: 'On vacation'},
                    { value: '3', label: 'Training'},
                    { value: '4', label: 'Sick leave'},
                ]"
                name="schedule_type"
                v-model="selectedValue"
            > Select type
            </cs-dashboard-select>
        </validator-v2>
    </div>    
</div>
<!-- Schedule type -->
```

here, I'm trying to display a textarea if an user selects the third option from above select list

```
<!-- Notes -->
<div v-if="selectedValue === '3'"  class="container mx-auto flex bg-white px-6 py-1 space-x-2">
    <dashboard-input-label class="col-sm-2 mb-2 w-full" identifier="schedule_location">
        Notes
    </dashboard-input-label>         
</div>
                
<div v-if="selectedValue === '3'" class="container mx-auto flex bg-white px-6 py-1 space-x-2">
    <textarea
        :name="`schedule_notes`"
        rows="6"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Additional notes..."
        class="z-10 relative h-auto form-textarea resize-none w-full relative z-10"
    >
    </textarea>
</div>          
<!-- Notes -->
```

But when I try to run this, this is not showing me the textarea even though I selected the third option...and I can't figure out the issue as well...

This is my dev tool screenshot

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could it be some styling that is hiding your `textarea`? Because you do not have an `v-if` on neither the textarea nor it's container, so there's nothing that should cause vue to not render it.

Comment: I have it here, <div v-if="selectedValue === '3'"  class="container mx-auto flex bg-white px-6 py-1 space-x-2">

Comment: That doesn't include the `<teaxarea>`. That div is closed before the container that has the textarea.

Comment: I've updated the question, it was my bad.. Still not working

Comment: Is the textarea shown if you remove the `v-if` from it?

Comment: Does selectedValue update its value? your checking it in devtools? Is it number or string?

Comment: yes, it shows the text area

Comment: @nosnart value:"2" yes

Comment: @ArcticFox It depends where you added this textarea element ? It is in same component where you have dropdown ?

Comment: There isn't any problem with `v-if`. After selecting a value from `cs-dashboard-select` what is the `selectedValue` value? it should be `'3'` (a string of 3). Would you please attach a screenshot of the VueDevTool section of data where `selectedValue` exists?

Comment: @Mr.R I have updated the quiz with dev tool ss

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I have updated the quiz with dev tool ss

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen I have updated the quiz with dev tool ss

Comment: Can you include the rest of your component? The screenshot you included is from the internal state of the `<cs-dashboard-select>`-component, which isn't really helpful in this context. We need to see the rest of the component and the dev tool state from the component you've built - not the select-component.

Comment: The dev tool ss shows your `cs-dashboard-select` state. Please do the same thing where `selectedValue` exists. I'm not sure, but maybe you should turn condition into `v-if="selectedValue.value === '3'"`. Please log the proper dev tool ss.

Comment: @Mr.R i sorted out the issue by using,  v-if="this.selectedValue=== '1'" thank you so much for your support